# IOS Status bar doesn't appear after ios update

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I will working with xamarin.form and my status bar was good, till the ios 11.0 update....
after ios update (11.0) my app doesn't show the status bar...Does someone know how can I show it again???
Is there a way to verify the version of the device?

Comment: Is there any code in your project to show/hide the status bar?

Comment: there isn't becausein the 10;3 it was showed

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated Xamarin.Forms? I believe it was updated when the iOS was updated to 11.0